# Проверка checkbox, если не отмечен, то не отправлять постом данные

Tags: php, javascript

Есть на странице поля с инпутами и чекбоксами, после нажатия на кнопку пользователь переходит на страницу с документом пдф, где выводятся его данные.

Вот вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы если не отмечен хотя бы один из чекбоксов, то пользователь не попадал бы на страницу пдф?

Я по-разному пытался, добился максимум ява скриптом, что он проверял чекбоксы, но всё равно перекидывал пользователя на страницу пдф.

```
if ( (isset($checkme) && strlen($checkme)>0) or ( isset($checkme1) && strlen($checkmel)>0) or (isset($checkme2) && strlen($checkme2)>0) )

{

    echo "Check is set";

}

  <div class="wrap"><div class="orderBlock">
    <form method="post" action="online-zakaz.php" id="target">
    <div class="orderForm">
        <div>
            <span>Фамилия<em>*</em></span>
            <input name="surname" class="orderInp" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Имя<em>*</em></span>
            <input name="username" class="orderInp" type="text">
        </div>
    <div>
            <span>Отчество<em>*</em></span>
            <input class="orderInp" name="threname" type="text">
        </div>
    <div>
            <span>Телефон<em>*</em></span>
            <input class="orderInp" name="phone" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>E-mail<em>*</em></span>
            <input class="orderInp" name="email" type="text">
        </div>
    <div>
            <div class="orderRules">
        <input value="Получить промо-код**" class="orderBut" type="submit" id="subButton">
    </div>
        </div>
    <div>
            <span>Подтверждаю свое согласие на обработку персональных данных<em>*</em></span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="usrname22" id="agree" checked="checked">  
        </div>
    <div>
            <span> Подтверждаю свое согласие на получение информации на e-mail и мобильный телефон<em>*</em></span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="usrname23" id="agree" checked="checked">  
        </div>

  <div id="qqqq">

  </div>
     <div style="margin-top:20px; width: 900px; ">
     **Отправляя данные для получения промо кода вы подтверждаете свое согласие на обработку персональных данных и на получение информации на e-mail и мобильный телефон </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
            </div>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script>
$('#formcheckboxExample input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#formcheckboxExample input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#formcheckboxExample input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действия примерно такие:

На форму вешаешь событие onSubmit. Там проходишь по всем чекбоксам, и если хоть один не отмечен, то возвращаешь false, тогда форма просто не отправится.